# GUI unknown error

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, syntax-error, braces

i keep getting this error message saying

```
Guess.java:205: error: illegal start of expression
 public String doConversion(String text){
 ^

Guess.java:205: error: ';' expected
 public String doConversion(String text){
                           ^

Guess.java:205: error: ';' expected
 public String doConversion(String text){
                                       ^
Guess.java:239: error: illegal start of expression
 public String doDConversion(String text){
 ^

Guess.java:239: error: ';' expected
 public String doDConversion(String text){
                            ^

Guess.java:239: error: ';' expected
 public String doDConversion(String text){
                                        ^
Guess.java:274: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
```

and i have tried literally everything i can think of, any suggestions?

heres the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Guess extends JFrame {
    private static int WIDTH = 750;
    private static int HEIGHT = 460;
    private static int[] count = new int[256];
    private int currentNumber;
    private int amtOfTries;
    private Random myGen;

    private int row = 10;
    private int col = 20;
    private int counter = 0;

    private JTextField lineTF = new JTextField(20);
    private JTextArea conversionTA;
    private JButton exitB, encryptB, decryptB;
    private JButton button0, button1, button2, button3, button4, button5;
    private JButton startGame;
    private ButtonEventHandler eventHandler;


    public Guess() {
        setTitle("The Shell Game...");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        myGen = new Random();
        currentNumber = myGen.nextInt(6);

        Container pane = getContentPane();

        conversionTA = new JTextArea(row, col);
        exitB = new JButton("Exit");
        button0 = new JButton("0");
        button1 = new JButton("1");
        button2 = new JButton("2");
        button3 = new JButton("3");
        button4 = new JButton("4");
        button5 = new JButton("5");
        startGame = new JButton("Start New Game");

        eventHandler = new ButtonEventHandler();
        exitB.addActionListener(eventHandler);
        button0.addActionListener(eventHandler);
        button1.addActionListener(eventHandler);
        button2.addActionListener(eventHandler);
        button3.addActionListener(eventHandler);
        button4.addActionListener(eventHandler);
        button5.addActionListener(eventHandler);
        startGame.addActionListener(eventHandler);

        //set the layout of the pane to null
        pane.setLayout(null);

        //set the locations of the GUI components
        //lineTF.setLocation(20, 50);
        conversionTA.setLocation(320, 10);
        button0.setLocation(20, 100);
        button1.setLocation(120, 100);
        button2.setLocation(240, 100);
        button3.setLocation(20, 50);
        button4.setLocation(120, 50);
        button5.setLocation(240, 50);
        exitB.setLocation(40, 140);
        startGame.setLocation(20, 190);

        //set the sizes of the GUI components
        //lineTF.setSize(200, 30);
        conversionTA.setSize(400, 400);
        button0.setSize(60, 30);
        button1.setSize(60, 30);
        button2.setSize(60, 30);
        button2.setSize(60, 30);
        button3.setSize(60, 30);
        button4.setSize(60, 30);
        button5.setSize(60, 30);
        startGame.setSize(270, 30);
        exitB.setSize(200, 30);

        //add components to the pane
        //pane.add(lineTF);
        pane.add(conversionTA);
        pane.add(button0);
        pane.add(button1);
        pane.add(button2);
        pane.add(button3);
        pane.add(button4);
        pane.add(button5);
        pane.add(startGame);
        pane.add(exitB);

        setVisible(true);
        conversionTA.setLineWrap(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    } //end of the constructor


    private class ButtonEventHandler implements ActionListener {


        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("0")) {
                //conversionTA.setText(""); 
                if (currentNumber == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Correct Guess! - New Game Started", "Correct Guess", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    amtOfTries++;
                    String s = "Amount of tries: " + amtOfTries;
                    conversionTA.setText(s);
                    amtOfTries = 0;
                    currentNumber = myGen.nextInt(6);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "InCorrect Guess! - Try Again", "InCorrect Guess", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    amtOfTries++;
                }

            }
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("1")) {
                if (currentNumber == 1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Correct Guess! - New Game Started", "Correct Guess", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    amtOfTries++;
                    String s = "Amount of tries: " + amtOfTries;
                    conversionTA.setText(s);
                    amtOfTries = 0;
                    currentNumber = myGen.nextInt(6);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "InCorrect Guess! - Try Again", "InCorrect Guess", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    amtOfTries++;
                }

            }
            if (e.getActionCommand().equals("2")) {
                if (currentNumber == 2) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Correct Guess! - New Game Started", "Correct Guess", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    amtOfTries++;
                    String s = "Amount of tries: " + amtOfTries;
                    conversionTA.setText(s);
                    amtOfTries = 0;
                    currentNumber = myGen.nextInt(6);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "InCorrect Guess! - Try Again", "InCorrect Guess", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    amtOfTries++;
                }
                if (e.getActionCommand().equals("3")) {
                    if (currentNumber == 3) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Correct Guess! - New Game Started", "Correct Guess", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        amtOfTries++;
                        String s = "Amount of tries: " + amtOfTries;
                        conversionTA.setText(s);
                        amtOfTries = 0;
                        currentNumber = myGen.nextInt(6);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "InCorrect Guess! - Try Again", "InCorrect Guess", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        amtOfTries++;
                    }
                    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("4")) {
                        if (currentNumber == 4) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Correct Guess! - New Game Started", "Correct Guess", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            amtOfTries++;
                            String s = "Amount of tries: " + amtOfTries;
                            conversionTA.setText(s);
                            amtOfTries = 0;
                            currentNumber = myGen.nextInt(6);
                        } else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "InCorrect Guess! - Try Again", "InCorrect Guess", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                            amtOfTries++;
                        }
                        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("5")) {
                            if (currentNumber == 5) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Correct Guess! - New Game Started", "Correct Guess", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                amtOfTries++;
                                String s = "Amount of tries: " + amtOfTries;
                                conversionTA.setText(s);
                                amtOfTries = 0;
                                currentNumber = myGen.nextInt(6);
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "InCorrect Guess! - Try Again", "InCorrect Guess", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                amtOfTries++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Start New Game")) {
                            //conversionTA.setText(""); 
                            String s = "Amount of tries: " + amtOfTries + " and number was: " + currentNumber;
                            conversionTA.setText(s);
                            amtOfTries = 0;
                            currentNumber = myGen.nextInt(3);
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "New Game Started - Start Guessing", "New Game Started - Start Guessing", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        } else if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Exit"))
                            System.exit(0);
                    }
                }

            public String doConversion (String text){
                String temp, newText = "";
                double inches, conversion;
                int y, counter = 0;
                char c;
                temp = lineTF.getText();

                if (temp.length() == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "No Input!", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    return " ";
                }

                newText = "";
                for (int x = 0; x < temp.length(); x++) {
                    c = temp.charAt(x);
                    y = (int) c;
                    y = y + 17;
                    newText += (char) y;
                }


                /*
                for (int x=0; x < count.length; x++) {
                    newText += " " + (char)x + ":" + count[x];
                }
                */

                conversionTA.setText("");

                return newText;
            }


            public String doDConversion (String text){
                String temp, newText = "";
                double inches, conversion;
                int y, counter = 0;
                char c;

                conversionTA.selectAll();
                temp = conversionTA.getText();

                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), temp, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                if (temp.length() == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "No Input!", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    return " ";
                }

                newText = "";
                for (int x = 0; x < temp.length(); x++) {
                    c = temp.charAt(x);
                    y = (int) c;
                    y = y - 17;
                    newText += (char) y;
                }


                /*
                for (int x=0; x < count.length; x++) {
                    newText += " " + (char)x + ":" + count[x];
                }
                */

                conversionTA.setText("");

                return newText;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use an IDE. Errors like this would be a breeze to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

If you properly indent your code, you will notice the the problem with some missing brackets. If you're using elcipe, hit CTLR+SHIFT+F, and netbeans SHIFT+ALT+F

After doing this, you will notice you are missing two closing brackets before `doConversion` method declaration.

```
    }    // misssing
}        // missing

public String doConversion(String text) {
```

And also one more at the very end of the page.

Comment: ah alright, but now the buttons 3, 4 and 5 dont work like the 0, 1 and 2 do, what is the problem?

Comment: Again, look at the way your brackets are set up. Starting from  after 2, all your other if are placed _inside_ 2. Use an IDE. You will spot these problems a lot more easily if you format your code correctly.